# Are these charts on enchantment probabilities still accurate, as of 1.6?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've found [these very useful charts](http://0xcafebabe.com/2012/05/31/minecraft-1-3-probabilities/) on enchantment probabilities for 1.4, and I wonder if they are still accurate with 1.6.4.

Comment: I imagine that they are still relatively accurate in 1.6, however, the data was collected before some changes to enchanting (added Thorns enchantment, added book enchants), so I have slight doubts about their utility.

Comment: I'm putting this as a comment rather than an answer, since "I don't know" isn't much of an answer. Not sure if the charts are still accurate, but the data that they pull from has been updated for 1.6.2 (updated 9/21/13) http://pernsteiner.org/minecraft/enchant/ Useful tools if you decide not to rely on the graphs.

Comment: @Unionhawk that's why he didn't write a chart for Books! thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some slight discrepancies in this data compared to similar charts for 1.4.6, a later version that included the Thorns enchant and enchanted books, found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/File:Enchant_Probabilities_1.4.6.zip) (and uploaded in the worst format possible, I apologize in advance).

When you remove the Thorns lines from the chart, they match the charts you provide. So they are *technically* accurate, but also not complete.

If you want to know the best level for an enchantment in an easy format, there is a website called [Minecraft Enchantment Calculator](http://www.minecraftenchantmentcalculator.com/), which uses the actual enchanting algorithm to either simulate an enchantment given a level and an item, or tell you what the best level is to get a specific enchantment on an item.